Existence of uncountable set of functions on natural numbers
For $f,g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ we write $f\leq g$ iff $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \{f\vert f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}$ be a set of Functions of size $\mathfrak{c}$ such that for all $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ the set $\{f\in \mathcal{S}\vert f\leq g \}$ is at most countable.
Can you construct such a set? Can you prove such a set exists? I tried a few different constructions but im not sure if they work:
$\{f_{i,x}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \vert i\in \mathbb{N},x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}, f_{i,x}(0)=i,f_{i,x}\upharpoonright_{\{1,..,i\}}=x,f_{i,x}\upharpoonright_{ \omega\backslash i}=0\}$ i dont think is of sufficient size.
$\{f_x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \vert f(n)=x+n\}$ and similar variants are too big. (as in for $g(n)=kn$)
Any help or solutions are greatly appreciated. A comment pointed out that CH is useful, but I don't know how to apply it here.

Using CH you can get a well-ordering $\prec$ on $^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{N}$ such that for every function $f$ the set of all functions below it is at most countable.

The chapter contains proofs using CH so that would make sense. But to take $\mathcal{S}:=\bigcup_{g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}}{f\vert f\leq g, f\prec g}$ won't work because even though the sets are countable you might end up with uncountably many of them under some $g$.

An explicit construction is tough. Out of a large set, a small subset is less than $g(n) = 10^n$...

Good idea, but as you correctly identified, this approach adds too many function at once. Can you think of a different approach that utilizes this well-ordering and omits smaller functions?

Ok so I start with the first $g$ and build my way up? With $S_0$ being the smallest $g$ and $S_\alpha:=\mathrm{min}_{\prec}{f\in\hspace{1mm}^\mathbb{N}\mathbb{N}: f\not\leq S_i, i<\alpha}$ and $\mathcal{S}:={S_0,\dots}$
